# Gstreamer Android Development

Tags: android, ant, android-ndk, gstreamer

I'm trying to compile the examples included in GStreamer. I'm following [this](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+Android+development) tutorial

but I can't compile any of the included examples because `ant debug` give me this error:

```
-compile:
[javac] Compiling 4 source files to F:\Android\gstreamer\share\gst-sdk\tutorials\android-tutorial-1\bin\classes
[javac] F:\Android\gstreamer\share\gst-sdk\tutorials\android-tutorial-1\src\com\gst_sdk_tutorials\tutorial_1\Tutorial1.java:8: package com.gstreamer does not exist
[javac] import com.gstreamer.GStreamer;
[javac]                     ^
[javac] F:\Android\gstreamer\share\gst-sdk\tutorials\android-tutorial-1\src\com\gst_sdk_tutorials\tutorial_1\Tutorial1.java:20: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable GStreamer
[javac] location: class com.gst_sdk_tutorials.tutorial_1.Tutorial1
[javac]             GStreamer.init(this);
[javac]             ^
[javac] 2 errors

BUILD FAILED
F:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:716: The following error occurred while executing this line:
F:\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 1 second
```

I have installed the latest version of android ndk and android sdk, I'm using API 19 and gstreamer 1.7.1 (gstreamer-1.0-android-arm-1.7.1.tar.bz2) downloaded from [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/android/1.7.1/); I'm using CygWin64 as required in the tutorial and ANT from Apache. I have also declared all the required local variables.

I can run the first command: `android update project -p . -s --target 19`

and also the second: `ndk-build`

If the compiling process is not possible with the command line, where can I get a working version of Eclipse with adt plugins?

Answer (score 0):

I solved: since I'm using Gstreamer 1.7.1 the import line `import com.gstreamer.GStreamer;` must be changed into `import org.freedesktop.gstreamer.GStreamer;`.